# How can I find multiple usernames that have the same class name in Python with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
    if type == 2:
        for p in range(1, maxpages + 1):
            link = url + str(p)
            driver.get(link)

            Users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("link span h5 hv7 secondary")
            print(Users[0].text)
            print(Users[1].text)
            print(Users[2].text)
```

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do with the code above.

I'm trying to find ALL elements that have the class name: link span h5 hv7 secondary (there are over 100)

And then print them out each individually.

error for Nic's reply:

```
User: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="39c90e31145c4cc21937f591facb1d2d", element="880b3920-08ae-443b-a7ad-621ffd988ce8")>
Age: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="39c90e31145c4cc21937f591facb1d2d", element="dc0297b0-f21f-4492-8be4-e14b5126d2bb")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 85, in <module>
    print(f"Text: {user_container.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f6.nowrap.truncate')}")
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 430, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 658, in find_element
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\VENA2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.f6.nowrap.truncate"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find_elements_by_class_name` you must replace each spaces by a "." as stated by @PDHide. This selected is limited to classes, I suggest to use `css_selector` with `find_elements_by_css_selector`. This allows you to mix ID, classNames, tagName..

The value you need to input is the same as a css query. First class must start with a "." and any classes on the same level must be separated by a "." as well. If their are multiple levels (child), separate with a space followed by ".".

More info on the css_selector with selenium [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) 
More info on how to build your query value [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Once you have your query done, you may interact through the list using a for loop:

```
Users = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("yourCssSelectorValue")
for user in Users:
    print(user.text)
```

From the screenshot provided, here a solution to get user/age/text.

First get the parent elements:

```
user_containers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.relative.flex-auto.mw-100')
```

Then get each Childs and print the results:

```
for user_container in user_containers:
    print(f"User: {user_container.find_element_by_css_selector('.link.span.h5.hv7.secondary').text}")
    print(f"Age: {user_container.find_element_by_css_selector('span.f6.fw7.silver').text}")
    print(f"Text: {user_container.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f6.nowrap.truncate').text}")
```

This is one way, but there will be a lot of read. 
**Another solution, you can also get all childs this way:**

```
users = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.link.span.h5.hv7.secondary')
age = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.f6.fw7.silver')
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f6.nowrap.truncate')
```

Then zip the lists and print the result of each:

```
for values in zip(users, age, text):
    print(f"Users: {values[0].text}")
    print(f"Age: {values[1].text}")
    print(f"Text: {values[2].text}")
```

Comment: You're welcome, are you able to share the html?

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this but I got an error: I'll add it to my main question

Comment: Also it didn't print the text, it printed a bunch of other random code or something (see above in the question post)

Comment: Can you provide the html source code instead of picture, so we can actually try the code? For the bunch... it was missing the ```.text``` else it was printing the element itself

Comment: The issue was with the parent element, I miss read the closing ```</div>```. I have update the parent element. Since class does not seems very specific to a User container per se.. you might consider the second solution a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

space in class attribute indicates multiple classes so use '.' instead of space to indicate multiple classes:

```
   Users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("link.span.h5.hv7.secondary")
```

You can use xpath or css to match exact class attribute value also:

```
CSS:

     Users = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='link span h5 hv7 secondary']")

Xpath:

     Users = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='link span h5 hv7 secondary']")
```

Example for using class with space:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")
sleep(5)
#browser.refresh()
elem=browser.find_element_by_class_name('RP4i1.UVauz')
print(elem.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
browser.get_screenshot_as_file(f"screenshot.png")
```

**Output:**

```
<img class="RP4i1  UVauz" src="/static/images/homepage/screenshot1.jpg/d6bf0c928b5a.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate classes using ```class_name``` selector.

Comment: @NicLaforge tahts an incorrect statement please try it and correct

Comment: @NicLaforge added an example for you to tryout

Comment: Wow.. sorry. I stand corrected! Never worked for me, even tried prior commenting..

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through them.

```
for user in Users:
    print(user.text)
```

Comment: I need them individually though, is that possible?

Comment: @Mario What do you mean?

Comment: Like... So the page is in this format:

Mario 23 Text

I need to get 
```
User[0] Age[0] Text[0]
User[1] Age[1] Text[1]
```

But they all have the same class name

So all users have class name: userclass
All ages have class name: ageclass
All text has the same class name

Comment: @Mario they are probably under a same parent class/container (i.e div)? Then get all parents, and then get each child based on each classes you mentioned.

Comment: This is the html code of it I'm not sure I'm pretty new: https://i.imgur.com/TMIGGXS.png

Not sure if you'll be able to understand any of that from just that picture but yeah

Comment: I can help with the picture, but if you can provide the source html code, it would be easier. As you might want to consider parsing with ```bs4``` module.