# find_element_by_class_name in selenium giving error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a button click using selenium but it is giving me the error. The html code of the page is:
[image]

The code i am trying is:

```
create_team=driver.find_element_by_class_name('ts-btn ts-btn-fluent ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon join-team-button')
create_team.click()
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other alternative possible for finding the button

Comment: Could you try the mentioned answer

Answer (score 2):

`driver.find_element_by_class_name()` only accepts one className, it's not built to handle multiple classNames, reference - ([How to locate an element with multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-class-names)), **THIS SEEMS TO BE UP FOR DEBATE**

Use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary.ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button')`

With `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` you can chain multiple classNames together using a dot(.) between each className in the selector.

Comment: Thats incorect statement you can find multiple class using class_name

Comment: Oh? I don't see anything in the documentation saying you can use multiple classNames with that particular method, using CssSelector is the correct way to search on multiple classNames.

Comment: jusyt have to replace space with '.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444957/6793637 can try out the example mentioned in this answer

Comment: @PDHide If you look at this SO post it is accepted that the `find_element_by_class_name()` only accepts one className - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-class-names)

Comment: @PDHide Every article I've looked up says that that method doesn't work with multiple. (https://www.nuomiphp.com/eplan/en/70157.html), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes#:~:text=The%20answer%20is%20No%2C%20You,find_element_by_class_name%20()%20or%20driver.&text=It%20accepts%20only%20single%20class,element%20with%20multiple%20class%20names.)

Comment: You can try out the example mentioned or can try out your self

Comment: @PDHide Either way, my answer still gives the OP a working solution as CssSelector will work. Have you tried using it with `find_element_by_class_name`? (http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2017/09/26/how-to-locate-web-element-which-has-multiple-class-names/)

Comment: see my updated answer , added the explanation and an working example from this question itself

Comment: your answer mentioned an incorrect statement that we cannot use multiple class was just pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
create_team=driver.find_element_by_class_name('ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button')
create_team.click()
```

You have to replace space with . as space indicate multiple class

You can use xpath or css also:

```
create_team=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button]')
create_team.click()


create_team=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button]')
create_team.click()
```

**More to answer**

If you check the exception from the by_class_name:

[image]

You can see that it is using css_class locator under the hood ( You can see it add . in frontautomatically)

**Working example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579491/find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium-giving-error/65579606?noredirect=1#comment115946541_65579606")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('overflow-x-auto.ml-auto.-secondary.grid.ai-center.list-reset.h100')

print(elem.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary.ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button[data-tid='tg-discover-team']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ts-btn ts-btn-fluent ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon join-team-button' and @data-tid='tg-discover-team']").click()
  ```

---

As the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ts-btn.ts-btn-fluent.ts-btn-fluent-secondary.ts-btn-fluent-with-icon.join-team-button[data-tid='tg-discover-team']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ts-btn ts-btn-fluent ts-btn-fluent-secondary ts-btn-fluent-with-icon join-team-button' and @data-tid='tg-discover-team']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```